# Script1014: Invalid Character replacing fetch with jQuery.ajax for IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm adding i18n support to an old javascript component. It didn't need xhr/fetch before, but it does still need to work in IE11.

I wan't to write:

```
    fetch("/libs/cq/i8n/dict." + lang + ".json")
        .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
        .then(function(data) {
            dictionary = data;
        });
```

But I know IE doesn't support fetch. We've got jQuery available, so I tried:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/libs/cq/i18n/dict." + lang + ".json",
        success: function (response) {
            dictionary = JSON.parse(response);
            onReady();
        }
    })
```

Now I'm getting this:

> SCRIPT1014: Invalid Character
>
> index.js (49,17)

I realize the `49,17` is referring to a position in the file, line 49, char 17.  That's the d in `dictionary = JSON.parse(response);`

I've tested the response, it's strict valid JSON.

For some reason `dictionary = eval(response)` is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that jQuery was already detecting that it was JSON and parsed it for me.

The `Invalid Character` error message was telling me that the string I passed to `JSON.parse` was an object.

All I needed on line 49 was:

```
            dictionary = response;
```

Comment: Odd this was the problem as it's not valid in any browser to call `JSON.parse()` on an object; you'll get a different error.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.